# std::stoi() error -- "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'"

Tags: c++

I'm currently on chapter 4 exercise 17 on Programming Principles and Practice Using C++, and the exercise is to find the mode, min and max of string input. I have left out the function to calculate the mode as it is not relevant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> sequence {};
    std::string input {};
    std::cout << "Enter a sequence of numbers:\n> ";

    int intInput {};
    while (std::cin >> input) 
        intInput = std::stoi(input);
        sequence.push_back(intInput);

    std::cout << "The mode is: " << findMode(sequence);
}
```

This is the **error** I get after inputting a sequence and terminating it with `|`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
```

I have tried this simple code to test out the functionality of `stoi` and it works just fine:

```
int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "4";
    int myint1 = std::stoi(str1);
    std::cout << "std::stoi(\"" << str1 << "\") is " << myint1 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This just means `|` is an invalid argument. Why are you trying to terminate it with '|' ?

Comment: @UtkarshDixit when i press enter, nothing happens it just goes to a new line

Comment: If you are typing your input, then the end-of-file indication is either Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z typed on a separate line, depending on your OS. I recommend saving the input to a file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the '|' can't be converted to an integer value and so stoi is throwing this error. If you are just using `|` as an identifier that input has ended, this should work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> sequence {};
    std::string input {};
    std::cout << "Enter a sequence of numbers:\n> ";

    int intInput {};
    while (std::cin >> input){
         if(input == "|") break;
        intInput = std::stoi(input);
        sequence.push_back(intInput);
    }
    std::cout << "The mode is: " << findMode(sequence);
}
```